# How to store historical data with symfony and doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to store store historical data with symfony2 and doctrine2. For example i am having 2 entities:

```
class Shop
{
     private $id;
     private $url;
     private $version;
}
```

and the second entity:

```
class Version
{
     private $id;
     private $software;
     private $version;
}
```

The Version entity stores specific shop-versions, for example `Magento 1.2` or `OXID eShop 4.7` - so a entry for a version-entity should be reusable.

Every time the version for a `Shop` is changed, i want to store this change to have a historical view for the version-changes.

How can i do that with symfony2 and doctrine2? I have tried many-to-many mappings, but i cant figure out the right way using the correct mapping.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things you have to set properly in order for this to work.

First, you need to tell Doctrine that `$versions` is related to `Version`:

```
class Shop
{
     private $id;
     private $url;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Version", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="shop_version",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="version_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $versions;
}
```

Since it's a `ManyToMany` relationship ([documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional)), `$versions` will be treated like an `ArrayCollection` by Symfony. Thus, you need to create methods to handle it accordingly.

**Constructor**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->versions = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

**Getter**

```
public function getVersions()
{
    return $this->versions;
}
```

**Adder**

```
public function addVersion(Version $version)
{
    $this->versions[] = $version;
}
```

**Remover**

```
public function removeVersion(Version $version)
{
    $this->versions->removeElement($version);
}
```

---

That's it. Don't forget to add the `use` statment for `ArrayCollection`!

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case instead of reinventing the wheel i would recommend Doctrine2 extension: EntityAudit that allows full versioning of entities and their associations. Usage:

```php
$auditReader = $this->container->get("simplethings_entityaudit.reader");

// find entity state at a particular revision
$articleAudit = $auditReader->find('SimpleThings\EntityAudit\Tests\ArticleAudit', $id = 1, $rev = 10);

// find Revision History of an audited entity
$revisions = $auditReader->findRevisions('SimpleThings\EntityAudit\Tests\ArticleAudit', $id = 1);

// find Changed Entities at a specific revision
$changedEntities = $auditReader->findEntitiesChangedAtRevision( 10 );
```

and more on: https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit

Comment: Hi Kamil, i need to be able to select the `Version` related to a `Shop` for a given timeframe. So i would want to track and audit changes, but have a historical view about changes. Does `EntityAudit` fit for my plans?

Comment: Yes, the global revision table contains: an id, timestamp, username and change comment field so you are able to query revision from given timeframe. points in time. To track entity history: 
$auditReader->getEntityHistory('SimpleThings\EntityAudit\Tests\ArticleAudit', $id = 1);

Answer (score 0):

Another available package for entity versioning is https://github.com/madmis/ActivityLogBundle. This package includes a revision control system that saves each state of your desired entities and properties.

To enable logging, add the following annotation to your entity class

```
@Gedmo\Loggable(logEntryClass="ActivityLogBundle\Entity\LogEntry")
```

Make sure to import the annotation

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
```

Add the following annotations to the properties where you want to log changes of

```
@Gedmo\Versioned
```

The package offers methods to easily retrieve logentries for an entity

```
public function getLogEntriesQuery($entity)
```

This will return log entries with the following methods

```
$logEntry->getVersion() //returns entities revision version
$logEntry->getOldData() //returns data state before updating
$logEntry->getData() //returns data state after updating
$logEntry->getLoggedAt() //returns when de log was created
```

In order to retrieve logEntries for a given timeframe you can extend the querybuilder that's returned from the following method, which is also available in the LogEntryRepository:

```
public function getLogEntriesQueryBuilder($entity)
```